# Js scrollTo behavior smooth

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Есть такой код, который выполняется при событии onWheel

```js
let delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
e.target.scrollTo({left: e.target.scrollLeft + delta * 2, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Скролл плавный только если крутить колесико очень медленно, но если крутить колесико быстро, то скролл начинает лагать.
Возможно это из-за того, что событие вызывается чаще, чем заканчивается анимация скролла.

> Как сделать, чтобы скролл не лагал на "большой скорости"?

Использовать какие-то плагины не буду)

Comment: А зачем вам это? Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Я хочу сделать горизонтальный скролл. Скролишь как обычно, а листается горизонтально

Comment: В таком случае, попробуйте использовать `throttle`. Он поможет вам вызывать метод скролла не слишком часто.